# firefeed stores only id in spark list - how does that work?

Tags: firebase

From: https://firefeed.io/about.html

> Why this structure? We're optimizing for performance and scalability. When we need to display the feed for a particular user, we only need to look in a single place:

```
 var feed = firebase.child("users").child(userid).child("feed");
feed.on("child_added", function(snapshot) {
  var sparkID = snapshot.name();
  var sparkRef = firebase.child("sparks").child(sparkID);
  sparkRef.on("value", function(spark) {
  // Render the spark into the user's feed.
  });
 });
```

I don't understand how you can just store the ids and list out the sparks. To me, all you would be rendering is a list of ids. How does Firebase know to get the data for the list of sparkids so it can be rendered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key lines are:

```
var sparkRef = firebase.child("sparks").child(sparkID);
sparkRef.on("value", function(spark) { ... });
```

This takes the sparkID from the list, and attaches a callback to the location where all of the spark's data is stored, under /sparks. This lets Firefeed use lists of sparkIds in various places, without duplicating all of the data for each spark. As an additional advantage, if the spark is ever updated, it will update in every list that it's a part of automatically, since the list is just storing a pointer.

Comment: would also be interested to know if there is ever a case we would store duplicate data, e.g. lets say a spark actually had images or videos stored in them. Would we still take this approach for listing sparks, when all we really want is the author and string?

Comment: Definitely. Especially with things like video or images, you tend to want to store those separately so you can easily get just the metadata for them, then load only the ones you intend on showing. As far as structuring your data goes, check out the Firebase blog post on the topic: https://www.firebase.com/blog/2013-04-12-denormalizing-is-normal.html